# How to change the color of words in jumbotron using the reference $jumbotron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I am learning web design and js .On my webpage, I define the default color is black in jumbotron h2.

```
.jumbotron h2{
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
}
```

define reference var $jumbotron = $('.jumbotron h2');
while running, I use `$jumbotron.html('hellow world'); ......` to display some words and I want to change its color but I do not know how to set new color while running, how to get the color value and assign a new value for my variable $jumbotron? I have tried `$jumbotron.color  =` or `$jumbotron.color('')` but they are wrong. I have not found any useful answers with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of an element using Jquery you can use the [css attribute](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

The code will be:

```
$jumbotron.css("color", "color-code");
// Where color-code you can set the color code like: #0fc0fc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the element like so

```
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
```

this targets the element by its id.  Or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("jumbotron h2").style.color = "blue";
```